# Getting elements in order with REXML XPath

Tags: ruby, xpath, rexml

I'd like to iterate through all the `<HeadA>` and `<HeadB>` elements in an XML file, and add a unique id to each. The approach I've tried so far is:

```
@xml.each_element('//HeadA | //HeadB') do |heading|
  #add a new id
end
```

The problem is, the nodeset from the XPath `//HeadA | //HeadB` is all the `HeadA`s followed by all the `HeadB`s. What I need is an ordered list of all the `HeadA`s and `HeadB`s in the order they appear in the document.

Just to clarify, my XML could look like this:

```
<Doc>
  <HeadA>First HeadA</HeadA>
  <HeadB>First HeadB</HeadB>
  <HeadA>Second HeadA</HeadA>
  <HeadB>Second HeadB</HeadB>
</Doc>
```

And what I'm getting from the XPath is:

```
  <HeadA>First HeadA</HeadA>
  <HeadA>Second HeadA</HeadA>
  <HeadB>First HeadB</HeadB>
  <HeadB>Second HeadB</HeadB>
```

when what I need to get is the nodes in order:

```
  <HeadA>First HeadA</HeadA>
  <HeadB>First HeadB</HeadB>
  <HeadA>Second HeadA</HeadA>
  <HeadB>Second HeadB</HeadB>
```

so I can add the ids sequentially.

Comment: Any compliant XPath engine must select the nodes in document order. Yours is obviously non-compliant. Strongly recommend *not* to use it and not to mistakenly believe that this is XPath.

Comment: @Dimitre: In fact, there is no specification enforcing the order of a resulting node set. This is hosting language responsability. You are right about that mostly every XPath engine will use the document order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, 2nd try, but I think I've got it this time :P

```
@xml.each_element('//*[self::HeadA or self::HeadB]') do |heading|
  puts heading.text
end
```

Comment: That did it! I've managed to turn my old 8 gnarly lines into 5 beautiful and clear lines. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Using Nokogiri to parse the XML:

```
xml = %q{
<Doc>
    <HeadA>First HeadA</HeadA>
    <HeadB>First HeadB</HeadB>
    <HeadA>Second HeadA</HeadA>
    <HeadB>Second HeadB</HeadB>
</Doc>
}

doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml)
doc.search('//HeadA | //HeadB').map{ |n| n.inner_text } #=> ["First HeadA", "First HeadB", "Second HeadA", "Second HeadB"]
```

For your task you could replace `map` with `each` or `each_with_index` and be almost done. Just add the code to insert the unique ID.

Comment: Thanks. I haven't used Nokogiri before, but that looks like a nice Rubyish kind of technique.

Comment: Nokogiri rocks for XML and HTML parsing. What's especially cool about it is that you can actually use the simpler CSS accessors for a lot of XML lookups.

Answer (score 0):

Would it work for you if you looped through all HeadA and, within each HeadA, loop through each HeadB?

```
@xml.each_element("//HeadA") do |headA|
  #do stuff to headA
  headA.each_element("HeadB") do |headB|
    #do stuff to headB
  end
end
```

Comment: No, they're not nested. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with a quick and dirty solution:

```
as_string = @xml.to_s
counter = 0
as_string.gsub!(/(<HeadA>|<HeadB>)/) do |str|
  result = str.sub '>', " id='#{counter}'>"
  counter += 1
  result
end
@xml = REXML::Document.new as_string
```

It's not the prettiest or most efficient probably, but it does what I wanted it to do.

**Edit:** Taking D-D-Doug's advice, I've now got this:

```
counter = 0
@xml.each_element('//[self::HeadA or self::HeadB]') do |heading|
  heading.attributes['id'] = "id%03d" % counter
  counter += 1
end
```

which is MUCH nicer.